# How to programmatically navigate the Schema View in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, add-in, database-project

I'm planning to develop an Add-in for Visual Studio 2008 that will allow me to programmatically create basic procedures for tables in a Database Project.

However I'm stuck in the very early stage because I can't find a way to programmatically navigate the schema view of the Database Project.

Does anyonw know how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to "VS Team System - Database Edition" projects? I came across [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/psirr/archive/2008/12/29/using-t4-templates-with-gdr-database-projects.aspx) the other day about using T4 templates with such a project.

Comment: Well, looks like my job was cut out for me. :)

Thanks